# What RegEx code do I need to leave something as-is

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a list of page names such as below:

> - Homepage
> - Product 1
> - Accounts
> - Sign In
> - Product 2
> - Campaign
> - Product 3

I want to use a calculated field in Google Data Studio to aggregate all Product pages. How would I write the code so that it still includes the other pages without manually inputting each individually? This is the code I have:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_Contains ( Page Title,  'Product' ) THEN "Product Page"
  ELSE [LEAVE AS IS]
END
```

What code would I write to leave the page title as-is but still including it? I feel like it's either something so simple or impossible and that's why I've been unable to find any answers. Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess just this:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_Contains ( Page Title , 'Product' ) THEN "Product Page" ELSE Page Title END
```